# Using Commands in WPF

Tags: wpf, model-binding

I have been trying to work through [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) for using commands in WPF and I am running into some issues.

I have installed MVVMLight from nuget and have been following along as best I can.  Bit I am getting Issues.

My ViewModel:

```
 Class BoreModel
 {
    public ICommand Updatesql
    {
        get; internal set;
    }

    private void CreateUpdatesql()
    {
        Updatesql = new RelayCommand(UpdatesqlExecute);
    }

    private void UpdatesqlExecute()
    {
        FormSql.ProcessFormLocal(form1);
    }

    public BoreModel(string BusinessUnit, string TaskID)
    {
        CreateUpdatesql();
    }
}
```

My Xaml:

```
    <Button Click="{Binding Path=Updatesql}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="206,211,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

The code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new BoreModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I get a error pointing to the bottom line: `"'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '17'."`

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `Command` property, not the `Click` event.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Updatesql}" ...
```

Comment: that worked!  I cant believe I missed that.  here is a quick question, on update of a text field, would I do the same thing to trigger the same method?

Comment: That's not a quick answer. Open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to set Command. Instead of setting command binding you mistakanlly set Binded with Click Event.

```
 <Button Command="{Binding Path=Updatesql}" ..../>
```